# How to access the text widget in tkinter for radiobuttons

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, widget

i want to access the text widget in my radiobutton but not sure how to any help is appreciated down below is the dictionary used for the radio button, i couldnt put it in the code section

global planets

planets = {

'Mercury':  '-3.81',
'Venus':     '-9.0',
'Moon':     '-1.7',
'Mars':     '-3.8',
'Jupiter':   '-25.3',
'Saturn':    '-10.7',
'Uranus' :    '-8.9',
'Neptune':    '-11.4',
'Earth':       '-9.81',
}
global planet_store
planet_store =DoubleVar()

```
def page_2():
    p2 = Toplevel()
    Label_2 = Label(p2, text= a.get() + ', What planet are you on? ')
    Label_2.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
    def clicked(): #when option is clicked it shows whihc value is being chosen
        global Label_3
        b2 = 'The gravitational force of this planet is: ' + str(planet_store.get())
        Label_3 = Label(p2, text=b2)
        Label_3.pack()
    def new_planet():
        Label_3.destroy()
    for planet in planets.keys():
        global r
        r= Radiobutton(p2, text=planet, variable=planet_store, value=planets[planet]).pack(anchor=W)
    button_c = Button(p2, text='Enter your planet once', padx=5, pady=5, command=clicked).pack()
    button_d = Button(p2, text= 'Choose new planet', padx=5, pady=5, command=new_planet).pack() 
    button_e = Button(p2, text='Next Page', padx=5, pady=5, command=page_3).pack(anchor=E)

def page_3():
    p3 = Toplevel()
    Label_4 = Label(p3, text = 'Hello ' + a.get() + ' you are on the planet ' + ' here'  ).pack()
    #i want access the text widget in the radiobutton and put it in 'here' of
    #the line above
```

Comment: just do one thing make the on value as your text

Comment: _"i want to access the text widget in my radiobutton"_ radiobuttons don't have text widgets inside them.

Comment: sorry im a noob and not familiar with terminology, what i mean is how do i access the text without changing the value

Comment: First you need to separate the line `r = Radiobutton(...).pack(...)` into two lines: `r = Radiobutton(...)` and `r.pack(...)`.  Then you can use `r.cget('text')` or `r['text']` to get its text.  However, since you create those `Radiobutton`s inside for loop, you need to use dict or list to hold them for in order to access them later.

Comment: thank you very much  but i was wondering why would i have to seperate the r = Radiobutton(...) and r.pack(...)

Comment: and one more thing i used a dictionary but the cget function only gets the last 'key' in the dictionary i want the cget value to pick the key associated with the 'value' chosen from the radiobutton which is taken from my dictionary